# TemplateRef type checking/declaring type

Tags: angular, angular-template

Lets assume I have component with generic type that displays data list:

```
interface DataProvider<T> {
  getData(): T[];
}

...
template: '<div *vsFor="let item in dataProvider.getData()">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rowTemplate; context:{item: item}">
    </ng-container>
</div>'
...
class AwesomeList<T> {
  @Input dataProvider: DataProvider<T>;
  @Input rowTemplate: TemplateRef<T>;
}
```

Some problem appears, when I use it:

```
<awesome-list [dataProvider]="provider" [rowTemplate]="template"></awesome-list>

<ng-template #template let-object="item">
{{object.name}} // Here, type of object is unclear (?)
</ng-template>
```

**So is any way to defined object/item class here?**

P.S. All this work ok, but I want to end with strict types, autocomplete in IDE, etc.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I assume you know that `@Input() dataProvider<T>;` is invalid syntax. Anyway, don't think it's possible for you to flow the type information based on the provider to the inline template but it would be interesting

Comment: @AluanHaddad thx, ofc it is Input dataProvider: DataProvider<T>. fixed

Comment: I'm assuming you're using angular language service in something like vscode? This is on the roadmap, but for now just defines these as any.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot enforce types for variables declared in ng-template .  See e.g https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28731

Answer (score 2):

According to angular doc, you can achieve this by setting the flags "strictTemplates" and "fullTemplateTypeCheck" to true (see more here : https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck)

I did a repro on stackblitz, sadly I don't think you see such errors with stackblitz, you could just copy/paste this in local and see if it works for you (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-strict-template-example?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Please note this is only angular compilation related, I'm not sure VS Code will give you the autocomplete

EDIT :
Bad news I tried locally with the flags set to true but it is not working (to me the doc is confusing because it says "Infers the correct type of components/directives, including generics.")
@amakhrov referenced the issue explaining this feature is not ready yet
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28731